# Can't install Ta-Lib with pip in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04, ta-lib

I need to install the TA-Lib library on python. Where I run the following:

```
pip install TA-Lib --user
```

I get this error code:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-52h2r7l4/TA-Lib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-meoq431k/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-52h2r7l4/TA-Lib/
```

I have also tried:

```
pip3 install TA-Lib
```

when I run:

```
python --version
```

I get:

```
Python 2.7.15rc1
```

Then I run: 
python3 --version
I get:

```
Python 3.6.7
```

I can't understand. I have Ubuntu 18.04.  Before I have Anaconda, then delete it (hope I delete it correctly) And then install Python 2.7 because I wanted to use Zipline to backtest some strategies, but I cannot use TA-Lib.

Hope someone know the problem, thank you!

Comment: Perhaps python tries (I never used ta-lib via python wrappers) to compile ta-lib from sources on fly and failed to find some dependencies. Try `sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake make` before that.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the problem was not solved. I don't know if it's because I installed and uninstall python 2 times, before installing a third time. I have read a lot of post and can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded [TA-Lib-0.4.17.tar.gz](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/05/d4c6a778d7a7de0be366bc4a850b4ffaeac2abad927f95fa8ba6f355a082/TA-Lib-0.4.17.tar.gz) that pip3 gets automatically. Opened it - there is no TA-Lib, only wrapper for it. According to its README.md

**Dependencies**

To use TA-Lib for python, you need to have the TA-Lib already installed. You should probably follow their installation directions for your
platform, but some suggestions are included below for reference.

*Mac OS X*

```
$ brew install ta-lib
```

*Windows*

Download ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip and unzip to C:\ta-lib 
This is a 32-bit release. If you want to use 64-bit Python, you will need to build a 64-bit version of the library.
Some unofficial (and unsupported) instructions for building on 64-bit Windows 10, here for reference:

1. Download and Unzip [ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip)
2. Move the Unzipped Folder ta-lib to C:\
3. Download and Install Visual Studio Community 2015
4. Remember to Select [Visual C++] Feature
5. Build TA-Lib Library
6. From Windows Start Menu, Start [VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt]
7. Move to C:\ta-lib\c\make\cdr\win32\msvc
8. Build the Library nmake

*Linux*
Download [ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz) and: 
$ untar and cd $ ./configure --prefix=/usr $ make $ sudo make install 
If you build TA-Lib using make -jX it will fail but that’s OK! Simply rerun make -jX followed by [sudo] make install.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did what the official site says to install on Linux and make a lot of things, but then tried to "import talib" and didn't find the module. After, I make a pip install again and it worked, for anyone that have the problem, please try that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ta-lib depends on their C implementation you have to install it before installing the python version.